# Compare arrays in Symfony

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, frameworks

I am trying to compare `two strings` if they have a same value.

```
 $userP = $userProduct->getProduct();

 $userC = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()->getProduct();
```

I  want to compare these two in two different array and want compare if `userC` has any value that is in `userP`.

How can I put them in array and can compare them?

Answer (score 1):

You can compare and find matches in arrays using `array_intersect()`:

```
$a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue","d"=>"yellow");
$a2=array("e"=>"red","f"=>"green","g"=>"blue");

$result=array_intersect($a1,$a2);
print_r($result);
```

**Output**

```
Array ([a] => red [b] => green [c] => blue)
```